# Xdb.Collection.Shard0 Login failed for user

Tags: xconnect

I have a Sitecore 9.3 instance. I installed on my local machine. After install, I moved my SQL databases to a server. I updated the connection strings and Sitecore itself is working fine. XConnect seems to work on a surface level - that is, I can go to my XConnect URL and get a timestamp. But, in my logs and my Event Viewer I am getting tons of:

```
Login failed for user 'myuser'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'MYDATABASE_Xdb.Collection.Shard0'.
```

I do not have an explicit connection string for these databases (The Shard databases). The user is set as a db_owner for the shard databases, so I dont think thats the problem?

How do I control access to these databases?

**UPDATE**

Its definitely still trying to connect to those databases in the old location (Saw in SQL log). How do I get XConnect to see the new dbs? Or rather, get the contained databases to see the new location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager` database defines the shards settings for each shard map in the `__ShardManagement.ShardsGlobal` table.

[image]

You will need to update the `ServerName` field in each record with the name of the SQL Server where you migrated your Xdb collection shards databases.

If you also renamed the databases, you will need to update the `DatabaseName` field in each record as well.